# Erro ao abrir um banco do postgres 12 (via postbird ou algo do tipo) -> column "relhasoids" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

Fui criar um banco postgres novo via docker usando `image: 'postgres:alpine'` e com isso ele pegava a versão mais recente (12.0).
Ao abrir o banco com o Postbird (que está com esse bug) e tentar abrir uma tabela, dava a mensagem:

**0.8.2 - column "relhasoids" does not exist**

e não deixava abrir a tabela.

Comment: Note que não é um bug do PostgreSQL, este campo foi removido da tabela pg_class do catálogo do sistema na versão 12. O bug está no PostBird que não fez a necessária modificação.

Comment: Exatamente, vou corrigir. Um problema que achei estranho é que os campos das tabelas não estavam visiveis em outro gerenciador (HeidiSQL), e passaram a ser visíveis após mudar a versão do postgres

Comment: Eu estava com o mesmo problema, fiz downgrade do Postgres para a versão 11 em meu Docker e resolveu.

Comment: A questão foi encerrada por se tratar de bug em aplicação (causado por falta de atualização), e não um problema de programação do autor.

Comment: @Bacco isso nao se enquadra em um problema de "ferramentas comuns entre programadores"?

Comment: @HugoL.F. ferramenta comum entre programadores se fosse em relação ao uso em condições normais. Note que mesmo fechada, a pergunta permanecerá um tempo razoável no site, o suficiente para ser consultada em casos similares, mas é uma solução passageira. O objetivo principal do site é ser um repositório de conhecimento sobre programação, na forma de perguntas e respostas que sirvam para um público bem amplo. Questões de suporte ou problemas pontuais acabam fugindo um pouco do objetivo, e note que no caso, seria questão de ler a documentação e ver o que mudou (talvez por isso os negativos).

Comment: Note que qualquer um que entender de maneira diversa pode votar para reabrir, e com alguns votos a própria comunidade consegue abrir a postagem sem depender de moderador. Ainda, tem o site [meta], que tem extensas discussões sobre os procedimentos do site, e você pode questionar a situação para a comunidade avaliar como um todo.

Answer (score 2):

Eu tive esse mesmo problema hoje depois de baixar a imagem do postgre v12. O problema não é no banco e sim na versão do postbird. Na versão 12 do postgre houve uma mundança de estrutura nas tabelas de sistema do banco. Pra resolver basta baixar essa versão do postbird compilada no dia 14/10/2019 -> https://postbird.paxa.kuber.host/2019_10_14.06_42-master-7a9e949

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: A versão **0.8.4 (64 - 7d97963)** ja esta ajustada para atender a V12 do postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Ao buscar um pouco na internet, percebi que a versão 12 teve algumas modificações que causaram isso, como a retirada desse campo ai de tabelas do sistema (ou algo assim).

Rodei a imagem modificando para `image: 'postgres:11.5-alpine'` e foi.

Ou seja, use a versão `11.5` pra resolver o problema.

Comment: Funcionou para mim! Obrigado!